# Accessing driver within docker container?

Tags: docker, permissions

I am trying to run some code that depends on the driver gigedrvframos.

When I try to restart the driver from within the container (without "privileged" = true), by running: `sudo modprobe gigedrvframos` I get:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'gigedrvframos': Operation not permitted
```

I can see the driver with lsmod, and it works outside of the container, and it also works when I run the container with "priveleged" = true. But I want to enable only the specific permissions needed. What permission/setting do I need to use to give the container access to the gigedrvframos driver?

Comment: In general containers aren't allowed to access host devices and can't load kernel modules (a given image won't have the kernel headers or toolchain for _this_ system's kernel).  How would you access this device normally?  Why are you trying to run your application in a container?

Comment: I added access to the device with the --device flag with docker. Our team runs our application in a docker container because we have to deploy to 100s of systems and this makes managing so many systems easier. But giving all systems privileged access to everything would also be a bit of a security concern I think.